# EL1008E: Property or field 'Usuario' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.String' - maybe not public?

Tags: spring-boot

Quisiera saber porque no puedo retornar una lista con los metodos que estoy implementando, estoy trabajando con spring mvc, recién estoy conociendo el lenguaje de programación gracias!

Entity

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id_audio")
private Long idAudio;

@Column(name="conn_id")
private String connId;

@Column(name="nombre_audio")
private String nombreAudio;

@Column(name="campania")
private String campania;

@Column(name="usuario")
private String usuario;

@Column(name="nombre_usu")
private String nombreUsu;

@Column(name="fecha_audio")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "YYYY-MM-DD")
private Date fechaAudio;

@Column(name="fecha_carga")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "YYYY-MM-DD")
private Date fechaCarga;

@Column(name="duracion")
private Long duracion;
```

---

ITbl_avt_audioDao

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT c.campania from Tbl_avt_audio c")
List<Tbl_avt_audio>findAllCampania();

@Query("SELECT DISTINCT u.usuario FROM Tbl_avt_audio u")
List<Tbl_avt_audio>findAllUsuario();
```

---

SERVICE

```
public List<Tbl_avt_audio>findAll();

public List<Tbl_avt_audio>findAllCampania();

public List<Tbl_avt_audio>findAllUsuario();
```

---

service implement

```
@Autowired
private ITbl_avt_audioDao tbl_avt_audio;

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Tbl_avt_audio>findAll() {
    return (List<Tbl_avt_audio>) tbl_avt_audio.findAll();
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public List<Tbl_avt_audio> findAllCampania() {

    return  (List<Tbl_avt_audio>)tbl_avt_audio.findAllCampania();
}

@Override
public List<Tbl_avt_audio> findAllUsuario() {
    return (List<Tbl_avt_audio>)tbl_avt_audio.findAllUsuario();
}
```

Al momento de querer hacer mi consulta me manda el error del titulo, ya he cambiado el tipo de variable pero cuando la cambio por un int me dice que lo mismo pero en vez de String dice integer

Comment: Sin el código de la clase `ITbl_avt_audio` no podemos ayudarte

Comment: Listo ! gracias

Comment: Una entidad que apunte a la misma tabla existe en tu proyecto? (`@Table("...")`)

Comment: @Table(name="tbl_avt_audios")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedo responder en comentarios todavia, pero me parece que faltan los getters y los setters de las propiedades de la entidad.

ejemplo:

```
public String getUsuario(){
    return this.usuario;
}
public void setUsuario(String usuario){
    this.usuario = usuario;
}
```

Espero que te ayude